# How do I get a Canon PIXMA iP3600 printer to work?

Tags: printing, canon

I have a printer Canon PIXMA iP3600. Following you steps this was installed without problems, but it doesn't print. The test page is sent to the printer and I can see it in the spool, but it never prints.

What can be wrong? I run Ubuntu x64.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here:

http://www.hrupin.com/2010/12/linux-ubuntu-10-04-driver-for-canon-ip3600-ij-printer

All is OK there, only that the installation of the deb drivers must be done with the command: sudo dpkg -i --force-all *.deb

The procedures I used forced the printer (Canon PIXMA iP3600) to work, but I met problems to install other soft because of the unmet dependencies. Finally I run the command the system recommended:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

without any packages and accept everything. This corrected the problem of dependencies but deleted the printer drivers I installed before (off course!).

Finally, the solution was to let the system install the printer when  a connect it to the computer and then going in to "System Settings" > Printing rigth click in the printer, select Propierties adn then, in the line of Make and Model click on Change. The system will offer a lot of drivers (in my case I selected Canon list), so I tried all the PIXMA ip drivers up than 3000 (The system recommends [PIXMA ip3000](http://www.canonprintersdrivers.com/canon-pixma-ip3000-printers-drivers/) but it doesnt work for the ip3600). Finally the driver PIXMA ip4600 worked for me, it prints the Test page.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip3600series
```

look here: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-printer-driver-canon-pixma-ip-series-on-ubuntu/